# How to convert data from database into a link?

Tags: php, html, database, forms, hyperlink

I have a list of courses that looks like this:

course

- SE1111
- SE2222
- SE3333

I need to show it in my page and then it should redirect to a page saving the value (name of course) for future purposes.

This is what I have done so far:

```
<div id="join_courses" class="">
  <form action="" method="post">
  <label>Join a course:<br></label>
  <input placeholder="select a course" list="courses" name="courses">
    <datalist id="courses">
        <option value="
        <?php
           include('student_register.php');//include php code that gets the tables (courses)
          while($table = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo $student_courses[0];
              }
          ?>
```

This gives me the input list form but it is showing me all the "courses" in one same field. (NOT IN A LIST).

any suggestions on how to approach this?

Comment: how about adding the appropriate html?

Comment: we can see that isn't full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with a proper anchor something like this

```
while($table = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo '<a href="yourPath/'. $student_courses[0] . '">' . 
     $student_courses[0] . '</a>';
          }
```